# ARC/ObjC++: C++ object inside an ObjC container

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Consider:

```
class SomeCppClass {
public:
    SomeCppClass() {} ;
    ~SomeCppClass() {} ;
} ;

@interface Test1 : NSObject

- (id) init ;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * container ;

@end

@implementation Test1

@synthesize container ;

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        container = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10] ;
        [container addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:new SomeCppClass()]] ;
    }
    return self ;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    for (NSValue * v in container) {
        SomeCppClass * c = (SomeCppClass *) [v pointerValue] ;
        delete c ;
    }
}
@end
```

Is this the correct approach to delete C++ land objects when you're done with them under ARC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work, but you may consider a couple of other approaches to avoid the `NSValue`:

- Create an ObjC wrapper that manages a single instance of `SomeCppClass` (and deletes just that one object in its `dealloc`). This can make them a bit easier to deal with in many cases (automatically converting `std::string` to `NSString` in the accessors, etc.) This is basically what `NSValue` is doing for you, but you get much more flexibility by creating your own custom class. This is usually my preferred approach.
- Store the C++ objects in a C++ container such as `vector` and then you just have to delete the `vector` and it's easier to pull things out. You can used `shared_ptr` to put non-copyable objects into a `vector`. It is understandable if you don't want the overhead of STL and `shared_ptr`, but they are readily available in Cocoa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate on the "more flexibility" bit?

Comment: Creating your own per-instance wrapper lets you treat the C++ object like an ObjC object. It lets you put it into collections without worrying about memory management. It lets you fetch ObjC types from it (`NSString` in particular). I strongly recommend keeping ObjC and C++ code as separate as possible, with only a thin layer of ObjC++ to glue them. These object wrappers are that glue.

Comment: I've seen this pattern used a lot, but it doesn't seem to cover C++ pass by value. If a method in the c++ class returns Object and not Object*, NSValue can't seem to handle it.