# How to add Objective-C++ object to a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c++

I'm creating an Augmented reality application in iOS using `metaio` SDK. In my application I have an object like following,

```
metaio::IGeometry* geometryModel = m_metaioSDK->createGeometry([modelFile UTF8String]);
```

I tried to add it to a `NSMutableDictionary`,

```
[_currentObjectDirectory setObject:geometryModel forKey:@"1"];
```

`currentObjectDirectory` is my `NSMutableDictionary` object. Is there any possible way to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ARC/ObjC++: C++ object inside an ObjC container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897495/arc-objc-c-object-inside-an-objc-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What [Amin Negm-Awad said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940651/404321) is correct. However, you could probably use a `NSValue` object with [`valueWithPointer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithPointer:) to wrap your C++ pointer.

```
NSValue *geometryModelWrapper = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(void *)geometryModel];
[_currentObjectDirectory setObject:geometryModelWrapper forKey:@"1"];
```

To get the value back, use [`pointerValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/pointerValue):

```
metaio::IGeometry* geometryModel = [_currentObjectDirectory[@"1"] pointerValue];
```

Again, as Amin said, you have to be careful with memory management. `NSValue` will not memory manage your pointer, and you have to ensure it is not freed while the `NSValue` wrapper is still alive.
[Read the doc carefully](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithPointer:).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897495/arc-objc-c-object-inside-an-objc-container) is very close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: If i'm unwrap it what is the procedure for it?

Comment: @codebot I edited my answer. I didn't test it, so let me know if it works.

Comment: @codebot Compile-time error? Run-time error? Error message?

Comment: I cast it like this. `geometryModel = (metaio::IGeometry*)[[_currentObjectDirectory objectForKey:@"1"] pointerValue];`. it's bad access. but 2 objects are in dictionary

Comment: Hmm. Hard to diagnose without seeing the full picture. Try to add a breakpoint and print the value of `[_currentObjectDirectory objectForKey:@"1"]` and `[[_currentObjectDirectory objectForKey:@"1"] pointerValue]`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add C++ objects to a Cocoa container.

You can use a C++ container or you have to wrap the C++ object into an Objective-C object.

Edit: Here are links about Objective-C++ (I did not check them.)

http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects 
http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/interoperating-between-c-and-objective-c/240165502

In former days, Apple had a documentation about that:

http://web.archive.org/web/20101203170217/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/web/20101204020949/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html

Comment: please give me a demonstration.

Comment: This is more than a one-liner. Basically you create a class having a property for the C++ object. But you have to take care about memory management in C++.